# Add NA to the top of a column

Tags: r

I have one column:

```
historic_unemployment <- c(0.0575, 0.1275, 0.151666666666667, 0.149166666666667, 0.135, 
0.104166666666667, 0.105833333333333, 0.106666666666667, 0.0725, 
0.0558333333333333, 0.0683333333333333, 0.0525, 0.055, 0.0408333333333333, 
0.0433333333333333, 0.0525, 0.0466666666666667, 0.0275, 0.0441666666666667, 
0.0508333333333333, 0.075, 0.0541666666666667, 0.0641666666666667, 
0.068)
```

and the other:

```
fitted values <- c(0.137023253252523, 0.130543486762516, 0.118735773791856, 0.109682083019129, 
0.10263866553188, 0.0837122001159384, 0.0580772899029193, 0.0531376546910345, 
0.0529651623490921, 0.0496381203970878, 0.0503647459492348, 0.0564917834527006, 
0.0565944213054081, 0.0445190657070135, 0.0335212669315816, 0.0357076018119224, 
0.0546613241321135, 0.0637659442126312, 0.0472901950013254, 0.0653375830289401, 
0.0677590453198192)
```

The fitted_values column contains 21 values, whereas historic_unemployment contains 24. I want to cbind fitted_values and historic_unemployment but, as they are different lengths, I can't. While I can find information about adding NAs to the bottom of columns to make them the same length, I can't find anything about adding them to the top of a column (where they should be in this case because the model contained lagged values).

I tried making a new column

missing <- c("NA", "NA", "NA") and using rbind() to stack "missing" on top of "fitted_values" but instead I end up with a row of 21 NAs and "fitted_values" is also as a row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with `cbind(historic_unemployment, c(rep(NA, 3), fitted_values))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important point: `NA` is a missing value, `"NA"` (quotes) is a string with the letters "N" and "A". You want `NA`.

`c()` is the command for "concatenating" - i.e., sticking things together (not as rows or columns, just combining vectors).

So, with that, we can do this:

```
filled_out_fitted_values = c(NA, NA, NA, fitted_values)
cbind(historic_unemployment, filled_out_fitted_values)
```

Or, skipping the intermediate step (and using `rep` to repeat the `NA` so we don't have to type it out)

```
cbind(historic_unemployment, c(rep(NA, 3), fitted_values))
```

Answer (score 2):

a custom function, it is always valuable to write your own function when the [DRY rule](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY) could be used:

```r
cbind_NA_top <- function(x, y) {
  stopifnot(is.vector(x) && is.vector(y))
  #this line have to be removed if vectors is not provided by symbols (variables)
  names <- c(as.name(substitute(x)), as.name(substitute(y)))
  x <- unlist(x)
  y <- unlist(y)
  len_y <- length(y)
  len_x <- length(x)
  dif <- len_y - len_x
  if (dif == 0) {
    res <- cbind(x, y)
  } else if (dif < 0) {
    res <- cbind(x, c(rep(NA, abs(dif)), y))
  } else if (dif > 0) {
    res <- cbind(c(rep(NA, abs(dif)), x), y)
  }
  colnames(res) <- names
  return(res)
}

cbind_NA_top(fitted_values, historic_unemployment)
cbind_NA_top(historic_unemployment, fitted_values)
l1 <- list(historic_unemployment)
l2 <- list(fitted_values)
cbind_NA_top(l1, l2)
```

I allocated an empty matrix filled with NAs as it is protecting us form doing sth wrong.

using `c`

```r
mm <- matrix(NA, ncol = 2,  nrow = max(length(historic_unemployment), length(fitted_values)))

mm[, 1] <- historic_unemployment
mm[, 2] <- c(rep(NA_real_, nrow(mm) - length(fitted_values)) ,fitted_values)

mm
```

or

```r
mm <- matrix(NA, ncol = 2,  nrow = max(length(historic_unemployment), length(fitted_values)))

mm[, 1] <- historic_unemployment
mm[(nrow(mm) - length(fitted_values) + 1):nrow(mm), 2] <- fitted_values

mm
```

Data:

```r
historic_unemployment <- c(0.0575, 0.1275, 0.151666666666667, 0.149166666666667, 0.135, 
0.104166666666667, 0.105833333333333, 0.106666666666667, 0.0725, 
0.0558333333333333, 0.0683333333333333, 0.0525, 0.055, 0.0408333333333333, 
0.0433333333333333, 0.0525, 0.0466666666666667, 0.0275, 0.0441666666666667, 
0.0508333333333333, 0.075, 0.0541666666666667, 0.0641666666666667, 
0.068) 

fitted_values <- c(0.137023253252523, 0.130543486762516, 0.118735773791856, 0.109682083019129, 
0.10263866553188, 0.0837122001159384, 0.0580772899029193, 0.0531376546910345, 
0.0529651623490921, 0.0496381203970878, 0.0503647459492348, 0.0564917834527006, 
0.0565944213054081, 0.0445190657070135, 0.0335212669315816, 0.0357076018119224, 
0.0546613241321135, 0.0637659442126312, 0.0472901950013254, 0.0653375830289401, 
0.0677590453198192)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to compute the difference of lenghts in vectors and do the bind like this:

```
#Code
cbind(historic_unemployment,
fitted.values=c(rep(NA,length(historic_unemployment)-length(fitted.values)),fitted.values))
```